# Придаточное определительное и обособленное определение

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

Подскажите, будьте добры, верно ли построено предложение?

**Существует класс людей весьма дурной, и на который я прошу вас обратить особенное внимание...**
Текст старый, но интересно все равно. Такова пунктуация в оригинале.

Как стоит построить предложение, если брать наше время?

Да и вообще интересно, можно ли использовать обособленное определение (причастный оборот или просто прилагательное) вместе с придаточным определительным. В интернете искал материал, но нашел лишь касательно причастного оборота .

(**Картина, весьма красивая и висящая на стене** — можно ли так использовать? Или можно ли так: **картина, которая висит на стене и весьма красивая**?).

Comment: _antonolove: Как стоит построить предложение, если брать наше время?_  === Как вариант: _Существует класс людей весьма дурной – и на **него** я прошу вас обратить особенное внимание..._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Розенталь:
Не следует соединять как однородные синтаксические элементы члены предложения и придаточные предложения. Положение это иногда нарушается, например:
*Целесообразны подвесные покрытия, прикрепленные к винтам и которые позволяют перекрывать большие пролеты.

Выступавшие в прениях, не возражая против основных положений доклада, однако считают его неполным.*

Еще чаще наблюдается в разных стилях сочетание в качестве однородных членов определения, выраженного именем прилагательным или причастием, и придаточного определительного предложения, например:
*По Пермской губернии идет превосходная широкая дорога, давно наезженная и которую я видел до этого времени всего только раз в моей жизни*  (Герцен).
Подробнее: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/67.htm

То есть это не рекомендуется, но порой встречается.

Наличие предлога в начале придаточного ещё больше увеличивает неоднородность — ухудшает стилистику.

При обратном порядке (придаточное перед членом предложения) оно не звучит. Такое не используется.

> Как стоит построить предложение, если брать наше время?

*Существует весьма дурной класс людей, на который я прошу вас обратить особенное внимание...*

Союз И там не звучит, потому что нет однородности: прилагательное описывает особенность этого класса людей, а придаточное — то, что предлагают сделать по отношению к нему (уже не особенность).

В вашем примере с причастным оборотом плохая однородность, поэтому не звучит. Но соединять причастие и прилагательное никто не запрещает.

Самое изощрение, если потом ещё продолжить предложение, например:
*Он хотел мороженого и чтобы застолье продолжалось до вечера очень сильно.

Он хотел чтобы застолье продолжалось до вечера и мороженого очень сильно.*